# Not able to run jersey + angular project

Tags: java, angularjs, maven, jersey

I'm following this example https://github.com/draptik/angulardemorestful that seems too cool, but I'm having problems to run the project because doesn't have mainClass, sorry I'm very new with jersey and angular too, I've already tried this:

```
mvn exec:java
```

and I have this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java (default-cli) on project ngdemo: The parameters 'mainClass' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
```

It seems there is another way to run java + jersey + angularjs together but I dont get it. Someone would help me please? thanks in advance :)

Comment: Looks like it has the `jetty-maven-plugin`. For that you use `mvn jetty:run`

Comment: @peeskillet thank you so much, its working now :) .There is one thing pending, it shows only "Hello World!" not with the angular example together,   am I missing something more?